# Incluindo o mesmo conteudo para diversas páginas

Tags: php, html

Estou desenvolvendo um site que terá uma quantidade crescente de páginas.
Gostaria de saber se podem me ajudar em como incluir o mesmo conteúdo em várias páginas da seguinte forma:

Todas as páginas são com extensão *php* porém programadas em *html*;

Tenho um arquivo *rodape_conteudo.php* e gostaria de incluí-lo na `<div id="rodape">`;

Tentei incluir através do código `<?= include ("rodape_conteudo.php") ;?>` que foi o que as pesquisas que fiz sempre me retornaram, porém, dessa forma, não tá rolando.

O conteúdo na hora que executo o site fica em branco, como se o código não retornasse nada.

Isso pode ser um erro na parte de `<?...>` ou no próprio código do *rodape_conteudo.php*?

Comment: Não use `<?= include`, afinal, vc não está tentando imprimir nada. Prefira usar `<?php include`.

Answer (score 1):

*Include* não vai funcionar com `<?=`. Essa *tag* é um encurtamento de `echo` no *PHP*. Se vc não quer imprimir nada, use `<?php`, e não `<?=`.